# How to promote hidden mongo node to primary?

Tags: mongodb

We are trying to implement DR setup for our mongodb replica set and currently three nodes in DR are configured to run as hidden nodes. We are trying to test failover to DR which will require promoting hidden node to primary and secondary respectively. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: mongo version is 3.0.4. Currently I am trying to reset the hidden flag and priority of hidden nodes to make them eligible for voting and become primary (by assigning high weight) followed by reconfiguration of replica set. It's working but am not sure if its right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> We are trying to implement DR setup for our mongodb replica set and
>   currently three nodes in DR are configured to run as hidden nodes.

As per MongoDB documentation [Configure a Hidden Replica Set Member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-a-hidden-replica-set-member/) Hidden members are part of a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-replica-set) but cannot become primary and are invisible to client applications. Hidden members may vote in elections.

The most common use of hidden nodes is to support delayed members. If you only need to prevent a member from becoming primary, configure a priority 0 member.

**Member Configuration Document**

To configure a secondary member as hidden, set its [members[n].priority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].priority) value to 0 and set its [members[n].hidden](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].hidden) value to true in its member configuration:

```
{
  "_id" : <num>
  "host" : <hostname:port>,
  "priority" : 0,
  "hidden" : true
}
```

**Configuration Procedure**

The following example hides the secondary member currently at the index 0 in the [members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members) array. To configure a [hidden member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-hidden-member), use the following sequence of operations in a [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell connected to the primary, specifying the member to configure by its array index in the [members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members) array:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].priority = 0
cfg.members[0].hidden = true
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

After re-configuring the set, this secondary member has a priority of 0 so that it cannot become primary and is hidden. The other members in the set will not advertise the hidden member in the [isMaster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#dbcmd.isMaster) or [db.isMaster()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.isMaster/#db.isMaster) output.

> We are trying to test failover to DR which will require promoting
>   hidden node to primary and secondary respectively. What is the best
>   way to achieve this?

**Note with WARNING:**

- The [rs.reconfig()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/#rs.reconfig)
  shell method can force the current **`primary to step down`**, which causes
  an [election](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#replica-set-elections).
  When the primary steps down, the [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod)
  closes all client connections. While this typically takes 10-20
  seconds, try to make these changes during scheduled maintenance
  periods.
- Avoid reconfiguring replica sets that contain members of different
  MongoDB versions as validation rules may differ across MongoDB
  versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it via using below code snippet:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient() 
cfgDict = client.local.system.replset.find_one() 
for mem in cfgDict['members']: 
    if(mem.get('host') == "hidden-node-1:27017"): 
        mem['hidden'] = False 
        mem['priority'] = 20 #assign highest priority 
    elif(mem.get('host') == "hidden-node-2:27017"): 
        mem['hidden'] = False 
        mem['priority'] = 5 
    else:
       print("NO MATCH FOUND... NOTHING TO RECONFIGURE!")
try: 
    client.admin.command({'replSetReconfig': cfgDict}, force=True) 
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: 
    pass
```

Comment: Instead of using forced reconfiguration, it would be preferable to have non-hidden members with priorities to allow the normal replica set election & failover process to determine the primary. Forced reconfiguration is only intended as a last resort to reconfigure a replica set with unavailable members. As noted on the documentation page: "Use this procedure only to recover from catastrophic interruptions. Do not use `force` every time you reconfigure. Also, do not use the `force` option in any automatic scripts and do not use `force` when there is still a primary."